# nosetests discover code in "_test" folder

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nosetests

I'm using nosetests to discover and run all my test code. I would like to place all my testing code in a folder named "_test" but nosetests will not discover my testcode in this folder using the default settings.

I've found you can tell nosetests to look for alternative patterns using a regular expression to discover your tests. For some reason I cannot get nosetests to work using a foldername starting with an underscore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

The default behaviour of nose is to ignore `setup.py` and all files or folders beginning with either an underscore or a period. Increasing the verbosity of nose's output shows this explicitly:

```
$ nosetests --verbosity=3
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
```

While it's possible to override this default behaviour *for files* with the use of the `--ignore` option - for instance, by setting it to a pattern that cannot occur:

```
$ nosetests --verbosity=3 --ignore='^$'
```

... this *doesn't* work for directories, because of [a hardcoded exclusion of initial underscores](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/00ae0930e3bfad41279a0899e8c699f2ac1ff209/nose/loader.py#L164):

```
            if is_dir:
                # this hard-coded initial-underscore test will be removed:
                # http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/issues/detail?id=82
                if entry.startswith('_'):
                    continue
```

As you can see from the comment, the nose developers intended to remove this restriction at some point, but since the issue linked in the comment was closed as "fixed" in 2008, that plan appears to have fallen by the wayside.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why it was excluded

Comment: @JustMe I'm not sure if this explains the behavior since the setting is set in the [`configure()`](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/config.py#L303) method by passing `--ignore-files`. Though I don't currently know why it doesn't pick up the `_test` directory.

Comment: @alecxe found the culprit and updated accordingly - check out the new link to the source :-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus oh, nice +1 :) Probably we need to reopen the [issue](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/issues/71) or create a new one. Good finding!

Comment: @alecxe [I've brought it up with the developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nose-dev/rFbVvMunqvc).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus thanks for the effort, I'll wait for an updated version of nose and try again then